# Erreur avec « ainsi que » ?

Tags: grammaire, prépositions, conjonctions, coordination

Mon professeur de français a signalé un erreur dans cette phrase, mais je ne comprends pas pourquoi:

> l'auteur montre la puissance du personnage en le comparant aux actions humaines ainsi qu**e** l'incrédulité de ...

L'erreur est signalé en caractères gras.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La phrase est un peu ambiguë. Il est possible que ton professeur analyse la phrase de sorte qu'elle porte un sens légèrement différent de celui qui tu as souhaité.

Première interprétation : l'auteur montre (a) la puissance et (b) l'incrédulité.

L'autre : l'auteur compare la puissance (a) aux actions humaines et (b) à l'incrédulité.

Si tu veux exprimer ce dernier sens, la phrase devrait être « ainsi qu'**à** l'incrédulité ». Il faut normalement répéter la préposition dans un groupe coordonné  comme celui-ci — particulièrement quand une telle répétition permet de distinguer entre les deux sens. :)

Si par contre tu avais la première interprétation en tête, tu as raison, la phrase est correcte.

*Révision :* Je suis d'accord avec aCOSwt que la première interprétation est plus probable, et que tu peux aider le lecteur à y arriver en y ajoutant « aussi que ».

---

P.S. Probablement que tu veux dire que c'est la puissance et non le personnage qui est comparé : il faut donc dire « **la** comparant » au lieu de « **le** comparant ».

Comment: On est bien d'accord. À qq secs près tu étais prem's sur le coup, je vire ma réponse redondante et vote +1. Bon... pour la forme... si tu peux ajouter que... c'est pas bien grave comme erreur... ;-)

Comment: merci à vous deux, je n'avais aucune idée de comment justifier l'erreur.